# How to close button dropdowns using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I want to have a series of buttons lined up and then be able to toggle them for a dropdown of text in two ways:

1. I want it so that when I, for example, click "Omelets," the omelet menu opens, and any other open menu button closes so only omelets is visible. Then I click "Pancakes" and the omelets closes and pancakes opens.
2. If we're now on pancakes, I'd like to be able to click the "Pancakes" button and have it close, leaving no menu buttons open.

I've solved the first part, but not the second. And I'm stumped.

I'm aware of the bootstrap tabs and toggleable pills, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it myself with javascript.

Here's how I got it working so far (I pared the code down a bit for simplicity). The HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- OMELET BUTTON -->
        <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#omelet" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="favorites">Omelets — Proven Favorites!</button>
        <!-- FAVORITES BUTTON -->
        <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#favorites" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="favorites">Favorites of Our Regulars</button>
        <!-- EGG COMBO BUTTON -->
        <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eggCombo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="eggCombo">Egg Combinations</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="">
        <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="omelet">
          <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
              <div>
                  <b>Cheese Omelet</b> — Choice of Jack, Cheddar, Swiss, Cream Cheese or Bleu Cheese
                </div>
                <div>
                  <b>Turkey, Spinach, Onion, & Cheese Omelet</b><br>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <b>Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <b>Chili Cheese Omelet</b>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="favorites">
          <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
            <b>André's Suggestions</b> — 1 biscuit & sausage gravy with 2 eggs & 2 strips of bacon; OR 1 biscuit & veggie gravy with extra veggies & fruit<br>
            <b>Whoopie's Breakfast</b> — 2 eggs any style, bacon, potatoes, toast, and large orange juice<br>
            <b>Nova's Favorite</b> — Spinach, eggs, and cheese scrumptiously scrambled and served with fruit, tortillas, small fresh squeezed O.J. and lots of salsa<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
          <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="eggCombo">
            <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
              <div>1 egg any style</div>
              <div>2 eggs any style</div>
              <div>2 eggs, 2 strips of Bacon</div>
              <div>2 eggs, 4 strips of bacon</div>
              <div>2 eggs, sausage</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$('.menuButton').click(function(){
    $('.menuDrop').removeClass('show')
});
```

But this only solves problem 1.

To solve problem 1 & 2 together, I thought something like this might work:

```
clickCount = 1

$('.menuButton').click(function(){
      clickCount++
      if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
      $('.menuDrop').removeClass('show')
      } else{
        $('.menuButton').addClass('collapsed')
        $('.menuDrop').removeClass('show')
      }
});
```

However, that merely gives me the same result as the simpler javascript solution above.

How can I achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use dropdowns. As you're using JQuery, JQuery has inbuilt classes such as `toggleSlide()`, `toggleFade()` that you can use when certain elements are clicked. This avoids the need of things like `addClass` and `removeClass`.

If you choose to use dropdowns:

Your main issue is that you're targeting by classes. I think it would be a lot easier if you had specific ID's for each button, and each menu, i.e. `#omelet`. In this case you could do `$('#omelet').hide()` when the button is clicked.

What you can do is add listeners to each button (`$('#pancake').click()`, `$('#omelet').click()`, Pancake, Omelet, etc. Then, when the button is clicked, check for the `collapsed` class for each of the other ones. i.e. if you click Pancake, check Omelet's collapsed class. If it's not collapsed, add the `collapse` class.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla Javascript one can use the `toggle` method to apply the `show` class and have the function that clears other active menus ignore the currently active one. No doubt this should be easy to translate into the equivalent jQuery code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Sticky Omelettes</title>
        <style>
            .show{border:1px solid red;background:pink}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
                let menu=document.getElementById('menu');

                const removeactiveclass=function(el){
                    /* remove active class (show) from all menus except current */
                    document.querySelectorAll('.container .menuDrop').forEach( div=>{
                        if( div.classList.contains('show') && div!=el ) div.classList.remove('show')
                    })
                }
                /* 
                    find all elements with class menuButton and assign
                    an event listener which adds the `show` class to current
                    targeted menu and removes this class for others
                */
                menu.querySelectorAll( '.menuButton' ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        let div=document.querySelector('div'+this.dataset.target );

                            removeactiveclass.call( this, div );

                            div.classList.toggle('show');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="menu" class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">

                <!-- OMELET BUTTON -->
                <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#omelet" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="favorites">Omelet — Proven Favorites!</button>

                <!-- FAVORITES BUTTON -->
                <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#favorites" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="favorites">Favorites of Our Regulars</button>

                <!-- EGG COMBO BUTTON -->
                <button class="menuButton btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1 collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eggCombo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="eggCombo">Egg Combinations</button>

              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">

              <div class="">
                <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="omelet">
                  <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
                      <div>
                          <b>Cheese Omelet</b> — Choice of Jack, Cheddar, Swiss, Cream Cheese or Bleu Cheese
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <b>Turkey, Spinach, Onion, & Cheese Omelet</b><br>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <b>Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <b>Chili Cheese Omelet</b>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="">
                <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="favorites">
                  <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
                    <b>André's Suggestions</b> — 1 biscuit & sausage gravy with 2 eggs & 2 strips of bacon; OR 1 biscuit & veggie gravy with extra veggies & fruit<br>
                    <b>Whoopie's Breakfast</b> — 2 eggs any style, bacon, potatoes, toast, and large orange juice<br>
                    <b>Nova's Favorite</b> — Spinach, eggs, and cheese scrumptiously scrambled and served with fruit, tortillas, small fresh squeezed O.J. and lots of salsa<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="">
                  <div class="menuDrop collapse multi-collapse mt-2" id="eggCombo">
                    <div class="card card-body menu-card-size">
                      <div>1 egg any style</div>
                      <div>2 eggs any style</div>
                      <div>2 eggs, 2 strips of Bacon</div>
                      <div>2 eggs, 4 strips of bacon</div>
                      <div>2 eggs, sausage</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


    </body>
</html>
```